# NODE.js and Javascript; getting one single line from serialPort then close

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to do the following on a Raspberry PI

I connected a Parallax RFID reader to a USB slot of the Raspberry PI.
I can connect to the reader, and read the tags that pass by.

I use the following code to read a RFID tag.

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
  baudrate: 2400,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]

serialPort.open(function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);


  });


});
```

Result of this code is a console that shows the RFID tag content in real time.

However, I want the reader to just read the first tag he gets, and then close down the connection.

How can I do this? The serial port stays open now, and constantly writes data to the console.

---- EDIT ------

With the following code, my connection closes down after a single read. However, the data console.log shows an empty variable. I think I need to skip the first entry....

```
// Variables for connecting
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
// Variable containing technical USB port details
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", {
  baudrate: 2400,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]


serialPort.open(function () {
  console.log('open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);


  });

    serialPort.close(function () {
  console.log('closing');
});
});
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is exactly what I would expect from the code you provided... so, what about continuing with programming a function that parses the data received? What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Matthias, The parser sets the RFID tags into lines, instead of outputting every character of an RFID tag individually.

The problem is that it doesn't stop. It proceeds to read, the serial connection doesn't close after one RFID tag read.

Ill edit my question with an edit.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't close because it continuously receives data. That's okay (or not?). Are you sure you want to use the readline parser? You may hook into this and provide your own parser - or use a raw parser and process the data later on. Maybe I didn't get you right...

Comment: I want to receive one line, a line that has a RFID tag, ex ABCDEFGH0001. Then, the serial connection needs to close. I just need one line. In some way, I want the program to detect that he has his line; then close down.

Comment: Output now is, for example;
open
ABCDEFGH0001
ABCDEFGH0001
ABCDEFGH0001
(going on infinitely)

desired output is:

open
ABCDEFGH0001
close

Comment: I will revise my answer and post another one soon!

Comment: About your previous posted code Matthias:
This is exactly what I want to do, however, the first line seems to be empty.... Is this a known occurrence? Could I maybe skip the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really only want to read *one line* (like posted in your comments) try to modify your code like this:

```
// make connection using readline as provided in your example

var line = null;

serialPort.open(function () {
  console.log('open');

  serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);

    if (data.trim() !== '') {
      line = data;

      serialPort.close(function () {
        console.log('closing');
      });
    }
  });
});

// now you may work with your "one" line:
console.log('line strored: ' + line);
```

This only fetches the first non-empty line received of course.

Comment: Matthias, I thank you greatly for your solution. It works perfectly.